# Is there any Roadmap creation feature for Projects in Azure DevOps as its there in JIRA?

Tags: azure-devops, project-management, jira-plugin, jira-agile

There is a roadmap feature in JIRA, through which we can create Epics, user stories and assign start and end date to them itself by simply dragging the horizontal bar in table.

[image]

With help of this feature we can perform month-wise/day-wise or quarter-wise planning for any project. Additionally, we can export and share with client too. I require this kind of user friendly feature in Azure DevOps too. I tried integrating a Epics and Features Roadmap Plugin, but its not giving precise results as JIRA Roadmap is giving. Its user interface is very confusing, giving some occasional error message. Plus, it configuration is also very tedious and time-consuming. Can I get better user friendly GUI in Azure DevOps for Roadmap creation?

[image]

Please Help. Attached screenshots for reference of both platforms feature. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

DevOps provides [Delivery Plans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/plans/review-team-plans?view=azure-devops&tabs=plans-preview) to review the schedule of stories or features your teams plan to deliver. Delivery Plans show the scheduled work items by sprint (iteration path) of selected teams against a calendar view.

If it doesn't meet your requirement, you could check the existing extensions to see whether there are extensions useful:

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=roadmap&target=AzureDevOps&category=All%20categories&sortBy=Relevance